# How To Match Characters From Two TextViews

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I would like to know is it possible and how I could take the characters (in this case numbers) from two TextViews and use those matching digits to perform an action based on the number matched?

Like for example I have in my activity two forms of text supplied from a previous activity via getIntent().getExtras from EditText inputs and in this activity I'm using setText() on those two text data into two different TextViews (TextView A and TextView B).Now let's say if TextView A has a 5 and TextView B has a 5,I would like to perform an action based on that 5 getting matched or say if TextView A has two 3's and TextView B has only one 3,how could I perform and action based on that one match and one non-match?

Sorry I don't have any code posted up it's just that in my activity I would like to accomplish this but I don't know where to start.

UPDATE:I posted my code to give a better example.

```
package com.fullfrontalgames.numberfighter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.urbanairship.UAirship;

public class Versus extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();
        UAirship.shared().getAnalytics();
    }

    DBAdapter db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.versus);

        final DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
        db.open();

        Bundle PassedOverAttackNumbers = getIntent().getExtras();
        String AttackerNumbers = PassedOverAttackNumbers
                .getString("com.fullfrontalgames.numberfighter.ANumber2Pass");

        Bundle PassedOverDefenderNumbers = getIntent().getExtras();
        String DefenderNumbers = PassedOverDefenderNumbers
                .getString("com.fullfrontalgames.numberfighter.DNumber2Pass");

        Button Fight = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Fight);
        Button Continue = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Continue);
        ImageView AAvatar = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.AttackerAvatar);
        ImageView DAvatar = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.DefenderAvatar);
        TextView AName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.AttackerName);
        TextView DName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.DefenderName);
        TextView Admg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.AttackerDamage);
        TextView Ddmg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.DefenderDamage);
        TextView ANumbers = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.AttackerNumbers);
        TextView DNumbers = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.DefenderNumbers);
        TextView NBlock = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.NumbersBlocked);
        TextView NHit = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.NumbersHit);

        ANumbers.setText(AttackerNumbers);
        DNumbers.setText(DefenderNumbers);

        if (TextUtils.equals(AttackerNumbers, DefenderNumbers)) {
            NBlock.setText("1 Blocked");
            NBlock.setText("2 Blocked");
            NBlock.setText("3 Blocked");
            NBlock.setText("4 Blocked");
            NBlock.setText("5 Blocked");
            NBlock.setText("6 Blocked");
            NBlock.setText("7 Blocked");
            NBlock.setText("8 Blocked");
            NBlock.setText("9 Blocked");
        } else {
            NHit.setText("1 Landed");
            NHit.setText("2 Landed");
            NHit.setText("3 Landed");
            NHit.setText("4 Landed");
            NHit.setText("5 Landed");
            NHit.setText("6 Landed");
            NHit.setText("7 Landed");
            NHit.setText("8 Landed");
            NHit.setText("9 Landed");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: So you are facing problem in getting the values from TextView's or starting with an algorithm to compare them after you have the text from TextView's ?

Comment: @ShobhitPuri the 2nd option

Comment: ok. Its still not clear to me that you want to get the number of matching characters in b/w two string or anything else specific?

Comment: What is the max length of string in the textviews?

Comment: @ShobhitPuri For example TextView A=12(3)45 TextView B=678(3)9 I would like to make the app do something if TextView B has a matching 3 in other words if both TextViews have a matching number I'd like to do something with that matching number

Comment: @HoanNguyen it's 5 numbers

Comment: Does the number you want to match always inside the parenthesis?

Comment: @HoanNguyen No I'm using the parenthesis as an example in my app I want to take that matching number or numbers and make a text string to save as a score pretty much.My question is mainly about taking the characters individually in a TextView and making the app match them up and do my action with those characters,not the whole 5 numbers

Comment: Does it matter if (A has two 3 and B has one 3) and (A has one 3 and B has one 3)?

Comment: @HoanNguyen Yes it does matter

Comment: Do I expect only one match or it can happen to match say 3 and 4? That is A = 33124 and B = 34789

Comment: @HoanNguyen it could be as many matches as there is matched numbers like in your example the 3 and 4 is matched but the other 3 isn't plus the other unmatched numbers

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29399/discussion-between-hoan-nguyen-and-cranosaur)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void findMatches(String A, String B, ArrayList<Character> matches, ArrayList<Character> unmatches)
{
    String D = B;
    int i = 0;
    while (i++ < 5)
    {
        char charToMatch = A.charAt(i);
        if (D.indexOf(charToMatch) == -1) 
        {
            unmatches.add(charToMatch);
        }
        else
        {
            matches.add(charToMatch);
            // replace the first occurrence of charToMatch with empty
            D = D.replaceFirst("[" + charToMatch + "]", "");
        }
    }
}
```

To use the function above pass in A, B and two initialize ArrayList for example

```
ArrayList<Character> matches = new ArrayList<Character>();
ArrayList<Character> unmatches = new ArrayList<Character>();
findMatches(A, B, matches, unmatches);
```

Comment: Actually you should change i++ < 5 to A.length() so that A can be allowed to have any length and so is B.

Answer (score 0):

You means this ?

```
String textA, textB;
if(textViewA.getText() != null) {
    textA = textViewA.getText().toString();
}
if(textViewB.getText() != null ) {
    textB = textViewB.getText().toString();
}
if(TextUtils.equals(textA, textB)) {
    //match, do somethings
} else {
    //no match, do somethings
}
```